# Use disfavoredLocations(_:for:) for Widget below iOS 17

Tags: ios, swift, widget, widgetkit, ios17

I have multiple `Widget`s for my iOS/iPadOS/watchOS app. I have one widget with supported family `.systemLarge`.

```
struct MyWidget: Widget {

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(...)
            .xxx // some modifiers
            .supportedFamilies([.systemLarge])
    }

}
```

I want this widget to be supported on new stand-by location so I need to support family `.systemSmall` as well (I want to reuse `body`). But since I don't want this `.systemSmall` widget in home screen's gallery I need to use [`.disfavoredLocations([.homeScreen], for: [.systemSmall])`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/widgetconfiguration/disfavoredlocations(_:for:)?changes=l_5) as well.

Unfortunetely, I'm supporting iOS 15 and 16 as well so I need to wrap this modifier somehow into `#available(iOS 17.0, *)`. But... this can't be done since there is no type-erased `WidgetConfiguration`.

Then I was thinking about something like this with the help of `WidgetBundle`:

```
@available(iOS 17.0, *)
struct MyWidgetIOS17: Widget {

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        var widget = MyWidget()
        return widget.body.disfavoredLocations([.homeScreen], for: [.systemSmall])
    }

}

@main
struct Widgets: WidgetBundle {
    var body: some Widget {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            MyWidgetIOS17()
        } else {
            MyWidget()
        }
    }
}
```

But... while

```
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    MyWidgetIOS17()
}
```

works,

```
if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
    MyWidgetIOS17()
} else {
    MyWidget()
}
```

does not.

Does anybody know how to use `disfavoredLocations` below iOS 17 while still reusing the `Widget`s body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue with an extension on `WidgetConfiguration` which uses `disfavoredLocations` just for iOS 17+

```
enum WidgetDisfavoredLocation {
    case homeScreen
    case lockScreen
    case standBy
    case iPhoneWidgetsOnMac
}

extension WidgetConfiguration {
    func backDeployedDisfavoredLocations(
        _ locations: [WidgetDisfavoredLocation],
        for families: [WidgetFamily]
    ) -> some WidgetConfiguration {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            return disfavoredLocations(
                locations.map { location in
                    switch location {
                    case .homeScreen:
                        return .homeScreen
                    case .lockScreen:
                        return .lockScreen
                    case .standBy:
                        return .standBy
                    case .iPhoneWidgetsOnMac:
                        return .iPhoneWidgetsOnMac
                    }
                },
                for: families
            )
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. I tried your solution before when I created the question and it didn't work. Now when I tried it, it worked. I will update your solution little bit if you don't mind.